# coreNLP & rJava installation issue from gitbub in R

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp

fellow stackoverflowers!

I was trying to install coreNLP from github as there is a bug in the coreNLP package that comes with R.
Now while installing the coreNLP from github using below

To download the R library and corresponding CoreNLP java library, run the following in R:

devtools::install_github("statsmaths/coreNLP")
coreNLP::downloadCoreNLP()

I got an error

---

- installing *source* package 'coreNLP' ...
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  Error: package or namespace load failed for 'coreNLP':
  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
  Error: loading failed
  Execution halted
  *** arch - x64
  ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
- removing 'C:/Users/animshru/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/coreNLP'
  Installation failed: Command failed (1)

---

After looking at many suggestions what I understood was 
i) I was missing the class file path for Java Home and added the same and tried installing coreNLP again.

> Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121')
>   devtools::install_github("statsmaths/coreNLP")

This time the error generated relates to the package/library rJava as seen below

---

Downloading GitHub repo statsmaths/coreNLP@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/statsmaths/coreNLP/zipball/master
Installing coreNLP
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpieUxG6/devtools3c0456877ca/statsmaths-coreNLP-caee22e"  \
  --library="C:/Users/XYZ/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests

- installing *source* package 'coreNLP' ...
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/XYZ/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'coreNLP'
* removing 'C:/Users/XYZ/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/coreNLP'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

---

I have installed the rJava package successfully and able to access the library for the same. Now I need to understand why I am getting this error of access issue to a rjava.dll file inside the package rJava.?
Has anyone encountered the same problem already?? 
I have double and triple checked the java version is 64bit same as the R.
Any hints folks??

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using CogCompNLP?

Comment: @Daniel Can I install CogCompMLP as a package into R?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: have you find any solution? i am facing the similar issue.

Comment: It is just setting up the JavaHome environment variable correctly! I am sure you must have solved it and progressed by now.